# Как разложить число на простые множители, используя решето Эратосфена?

Tags: c++

Только смог осилить решето...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  
#include <math.h>  

using namespace std;
int main()
{
const int N = 200;
bool a[N] = { 0 };
unsigned int n, i, j;
for (i = 2; i < N; i++)  a[i] = 1;

n = sqrt(double(N));

for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    if (a[i])
        for (j = i * 2; j < N; j += i)
            a[j] = 0;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    if (a[i])
        cout << i << "  ";       

cout << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: И в чём конкретно проблема?

Comment: Как разложить число используя решето Эратосфена?

Comment: Это у вас в заголовке написано. Для разложения на простые множители нужно искать простые делители.

Comment: Как мне это сделать?

Comment: Ну у вас уже есть простые числа (наверное), в чём проблема найти среди них делители?

Answer (score 1):

Во первых думаю писать так будет чуть быстрей.
Это будет видно при больших числах

```
for(int i = 1;i <= sqrt(n);++i)
    if(a[i])
        for(int j = i * i;j <= n;j += i)
            a[j] = 0
```

А ответ на ваш вопрос. Можно и не делать решето.

```
for(int i = 2;;++i){
    if(n % i){
        while(n % i == 0){
            n = n / i;
        }
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    if(n <= 1)break;
}
```

Выйдут все простые делители числа n.
А если хотите делать с решето то на словах объясню.

Надо пройтись через все числа которые меньше N(проверяемое число) в решето.Если у него 1 значит это простое число и проверяем делит ли он N. Если да то выводите. Теперь у вас все делители числа N.

Answer (score 0):

Брать простое число и делить на него исходное число, пока остаток от деления не перестанет быть равным нулю. Потом переходить к следующему простому числу.

Comment: Только сначала попробовать это же ещё раз.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Первое предложение подразумевает множество делений.

Comment: @AnT А откуда у него возьмутся простые числа? Из решета.